Continuous loop and "Invalid grant" error during token refresh
I am using an angular application as client and Dotnet server as my backend. After logging in using a custom Dotnet authorization server that implements Openiddict and using the angular-auth-oidc-client package version 17, I encountered a continuous loop issue during token refresh. The token refresh enters into a loop of calls to connect/token, with each call being canceled and replaced by another call. This loop eventually ends with an "Invalid grant" error. This causes 100% CPU utilization in the authorization server, leading to the application being slow overall.
Operating System: Windows
Angular Version: Version 17
Package Configuration:
    authority: ********,
    redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    clientId: ********,
    scope: ********,
    responseType: 'code',
    silentRenew: true,
    renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 120,
    useRefreshToken: true,
    logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
    ignoreNonceAfterRefresh: true,

Server Environment:
    Dotnet Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version=8.0.0
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version=8.0.0
    OpenIddict.AspNetCore Version=4.9.0
    OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore Version=4.9.0
    OpenIddict.Quartz Version=4.9.0
    Quartz.Extensions.Hosting Version=3.8.0

Console error
Network tab error
Steps to reproduce the behavior

Log in to the application using the custom Dotnet authorization server.
Wait until either the ID token or the access token expires.
The application attempts to refresh the token by calling the endpoint connect/token.
Observe that after a few successful silent refresh calls, the refresh call starts to fail, leading to a continuous loop of calls to connect/token.
Eventually, the final call fails with an error message stating "Invalid grant."

This error mostly occurs when the application is idle for long time.
Application source code - https://github.com/JoelDennyJoseph/AuthTestApp
The token refresh should occur smoothly without entering into a continuous loop, and there should be no "Invalid grant" error.

you can check if you have correct redirect URI, and Check if you have added the assets Configuration in your angular.Json , If you're using registered cookie scheme as the default, There will be a default expiration time configuration. If you want to change that, then put a Configure for the cookie options for the cookie scheme and tweak the config values
